# Click only lockscreen?

Tags: unity, tablet

I'm currently running Ubuntu on my Split x2 and have almost everything working. I have OnBoard pinned on the side bar so when I'm using it as a table I can still type, the only annoying thing is I have to remember to open OnBoard before locking my computer, otherwise I have to plug in the tablet to the keyboard in order to log back in with the password. 
Is there any way to get OnBoard to open automatically when in the lock screen, or a possible way to have a click only lock screen (like a pattern unlock)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the log-in screen you should see a menu bar at the top. One of the icons (the accessibility man) allows you to open onboard without logging in.

Comment: Hmm It is there on the log in screen thank you, but theres still nothing on the lock screen. Also there is an issue with a 'ghost' display with the split-x2 touch screen and ubuntu. it's as easy as disabling the display from the settings, but this 'ghost' screen is enabled on the login screen, so the touch calibration is off :(

Comment: Yes, if you click switch user on the lock screen it will take you back to the login screen where you can access onboard as per normal.

Comment: sweet, now i just have to figure out how to calibrate the touch on the lock screen. thank you!